# ROSTOPIC publish every 1 second a new data

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, frequency

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey all,

I would like to publish a rostopic that countains a certain data every 1 second, and i would like that the data change in every publish.
Maybe read from a text file and publish line by line every 1 second or publish the output from a math function ...
How can i do that ?
I'm only using a cmd like this (rostopic pub my_topic std_msgs/String "hello there")  and i can't figure it out, i've being looking for a solution online but couldn't find it.
Please help me.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/350701/rostopic-publish-every-1-second-a-new-data/) by [Primo](https://answers.ros.org/users/53513/primo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2020-04-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I would like to publish a rostopic that countains a certain data every 1 second [..] I'm only using a cmd like this (rostopic pub my_topic std_msgs/String "hello there")

This is not something `rostopic` is designed for.

You'll have to write a node for this.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0